# How to utilise stored procedure with temp tables in Power BI?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, powerbi

I'd like to use stored procedure containing temp tables as data source for Power Bi.

I've tried:

```
[Query="EXECUTE [kpi].[KPI_NV]"])
```

and

```
Sql.Database("CZPHADDWH01\DEV", "DWH_Staging", [Query="EXECUTE [kpi].[KPI_NV]"])
```

which both raises an error

> Details: "Microsoft SQL: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Database'.
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '])'."

Using openquery (not prefered)

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY ([CZPHADDWH01\DEV], 'EXEC DWH_Staging.kpi.KPI_NV')
```

which raises

> Details: "Microsoft SQL: The metadata could not be determined because
>   statement 'INSERT #Regions (RegionId,[SalesRegionName])       SELECT
>   [SalesRegionId],[SalesRegionName]         FROM dim' in procedure 'KPI_NV'
>   uses a temp table."

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @M.Ali SQL Server 2016

Comment: when calling stored procedure use [`WITH RESULT SETS`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2356/overview-of-with-result-sets-feature-of-sql-server-2012/) option.

Comment: @M.Ali Do you mean [Query="EXECUTE [kpi].[KPI_NV] WITH RESULT SETS"])? That makes no difference.

Comment: No that is not it, there is more to it, I have provided the hyperlink in my last comment, read it.

Comment: The error is very misleading but WITH RESULT SETS solved me a similar problem.